# what make and model is this bike please?

Tags: identify-this-bike, cruiser

Please help me identify this bike, I have looked in a 
multitude of places and come up with nothing.
It looks to be a beach cruiser.[image]

Comment: A little weird -- appears to be fairly recent vintage (looks like a V-brake on the front), but those wheels have to be at least 48-spoke ones.  My guess is a European "city bike" design.

Comment: It could be a custom build.

Comment: When I first saw the image i though of Electra bikes, a sun company of Trek. However the bike in question looks too old to be one of theirs as they are a relatively new company. But check the website as it might have what your looking for

Comment: I don't know the make, but the technical term for a bike like that is a "low-rider". More photos might help. And see if there's a serial number on the frame.

Comment: Hi @user14256, a bit more context might help. For example: what country is this in? Is the bike new or very well maintained? Are there any markings anywhere on the frame?

Comment: How is anyone supposed to pedal on this thing? Force on the pedals will push you backwards and there is no backrest. This is like a half-assed recumbent.

Answer (score 6):

This bicycle is a Micargi Mustang.

See [this Google search](https://www.google.com.au/?q=bicycle+Micargi+mustang).

An an image from [this website](http://www.bigtimecruisers.com/Micargi-MUSTANG-GTS-Stretch-Beach-Cruiser-Bicycle_p_112.html):

[image]

Comment: The above bike and the Chubby Stretch Cruiser referenced by @user3811719 appear to use the identical frame, right down to the pointy end of the seat stay and the little squiggle in the chain stay.

Comment: That's useful - can you please edit your answer to add more information?   How do you know this - did you own one?   Where in the world might you have seen one?  How long ago - are they old or new/retro ?  Please flesh out your answer.   Answers this short risk deletion for "length and content"

Answer (score 4):

Just had a little Google for it (town bike cruiser green) and found it it on Pinterest. The bike is a "Chubby's Custom Green Stretch Cruiser" price is $324.99. Website is www.chubbysbikes.com

Answer (score 0):

The frame looks like a Firmstrong cruiser converted into a low rider

Comment: Welcome to the site - thank you for your answer. Would you be able to expand it with further information?    https://www.firmstrong.com/products/firmstrong-urban-deluxe-single-speed-mens-26-stretch-cruiser looks relevant without any modifications required.  However there seem to be multiple brands with a bike that looks similar, so ultimately it might be a far-east design wholesaled to various assemblers rather than a specific brand.